# Is an openVPN with ipv6 more secure than PPTP VPN with ipv4?

Tags: openvpn, ipv6, ipv4, pptp, internet-security

I have heard that using ipv6 in combination with a PPTP vpn can expose your true ip address, so I have been using a PPTP VPN with ipv4 for the past few months. I am considering switching to an openVPN because of the higher encryption, but it doesn't want to connect, it appears to be because I still have ipv6 disabled. Which is more secure? Ipv6 + openVPN or ipv4 + PPTP?

Comment: Does your VPN leaks any of your real address IPv4 or IPv6? That's the question. I recently remarks that my VPN (SoftEther) hide my IPv4 real IP address but leaks my real IPv6 IP address!!! Check here: http://test-ipv6.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open-vpn is much secure than ipv4 VPN pptp, thats for the higher encryption used in open-vpn and for pptp was hacked several times with certain level of ease, and also was broken down by NSA and that's make it vulnerable.
Open-vpn is relatively new in the field of networking, that would make it difficult to break at least in the near future.
Open-vpn is open source, which means it is backed by a community of developers that will catch any bugs and faults on the spot, also open source advantage makes it highly customizable and secure.

Comment: While I'd like to agree with this sentiment, it is in some respects misguided - PPTP is in many/most cases breakable by anyone with some technical knowledge and Internet access.  That OpenVPN is open source is not an endorsement of its security - heartbleed and shellshock both being recent  demonstrations just how lax real oversite is - but in this case its certainly better then PPTP.  I point out that PPTP implementations are also open-source (and rely on PPTP)

Answer (score 7):

OpenVPN is more secure then PPTP.   I don't think there are any fundamental differences between IPV4 and IPV6 from the point of view of the tunnel, save that IPV6 has more space.

I think you will find PPTP is fundamentally broken - see [here.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45509/are-there-any-known-vulnerabilities-in-pptp-vpns-when-configured-properly) - the only use case I can see for it is "ease of use" when setting up with clients that don't support OpenVPN - but both Android and Mac now support OpenVPN.

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN's security makes heavy use of SSL/TLS transmitting data across the wire, and the recommended authentication is through using PKI. If implemented correctly and configured properly, OpenVPN can be considered secure.

This all depends on you knowing what you are doing. For example, if you configured it to use 1024 bit RSA certificates for authentication, that is now considered weak. Using/not using a static hmac key can also have an overall effect on the overall security - the ISP in my country actively attacks OpenVPN traffic, without a static auth key I would not be able to establish a tunnel.

OpenVPN now allows you to use a couple of SSL librarries, OpenSSL (since LibreSSL is said to be API compatible with OpenSSL, it may work, but I haven't tried it myself) and PolarSSL. For example, I compiled OpenVPN from source on my VPS and told it to use PolarSSL instead of OpenSSL, and thus my server was immune to heartblead, but not some of my clients.

Do your research, lookup on best practices.